# Codeigniter how to show a result function in a view

Tags: codeigniter, view, controller, codeigniter-3

How to show the result of `function day_s()` in a view `just_organize/administrador/index`

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Admin extends MY_Controller {

 public function index()
 {
    $this->load->view("layouts/header");
    $this->load->view("layouts/navbar");
    $this->load->view("just_organize/administrador/index");
    $this->load->view("layouts/footer");
 }
 public function day_s(){
    $time = date("H");
    $timezone = date("e");
    if ($time < "12") {
        $greeting= "Good morning";
    } else
    if ($time >= "12" && $time < "17") {
        $greeting= "Good afternoon";
    } else
    if ($time >= "17" && $time < "19") {
        $greeting= "Good evening";
    } else
    if ($time >= "19") {
        $greeting= "Good night";
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**JUst add these lines in your index :**

use $greetings variable in view

```
 public function index()
{
  $data['greetings'] = $this->day_s();
  $this->load->view("layouts/header");
  $this->load->view("layouts/navbar");
  $this->load->view("just_organize/administrador/index", $data);
  $this->load->view("layouts/footer");
}
```

**Your day_s function should return $greeting:**

```
 public function day_s(){
  $time = date("H");
  $timezone = date("e");
  if ($time < "12") {
    $greeting= "Good morning";
  } else
  if ($time >= "12" && $time < "17") {
    $greeting= "Good afternoon";
  } else
  if ($time >= "17" && $time < "19") {
    $greeting= "Good evening";
  } else
  if ($time >= "19") {
    $greeting= "Good night";
  }
  return $greeting;
 }
```

Comment: Message: Undefined variable: greetings :(

Comment: check $greetings with !empty() function Like if (!empty($greetings)) echo $greetings

Comment: if my answer helps you pls don't hesitate to check it as green